# How to read view values in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get username value from my view in my controller but i am getting a null:

**Here is my View:**

```
<form action="Home/Save" method=post >
```

Name: 

    @Html.TextBox("Name")




    


`

Here is my modified controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
```

I would like to change this code so i can capture the textbox value in my Save action.

Please let me know if i am missing something.
Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of problem about your code. First you should read more about mvc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the view controls inside a Form ?

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/09/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios.aspx

[image]
<sub>(source: [scottgu.com](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/mvc4/step33.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I assume your editor template only contains the html layout code. If that's the case, the reason you are not getting the value is because you have not put your html controls in the forms.

In order for the controller to get the value, you need to post it via a form, Like this

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Submit")){
    EmpNo:
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userName)
    <br/>
    Password:
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.pwd)
    <br/>
    <input type=submit id=sbmt value=save />   
}
```

Note, my syntax will only work if you are using Razor template with MVC 3. Also, server side control is really for asp.net webform, try not to use it in MVC. You should be  javascript code to hide and show panel.

Comment: if you find the tips been helpful, please upvote the response

Answer (score 0):

I have referred to this example and it helped me:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=705

Thanks for your help Jack & vTortala.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a Model for Simple Interest

```
namespace CalculateSimpleInterest.Models  
{  
    public class SimpleInterestModel  
    {  
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }  
        public decimal Rate { get; set; }  
        public int Year { get; set; }  
    }  
}
```

Step 2: Create an action method that renders a view on the UI

We are passing an empty model to be bound to the view.

```
public ActionResult SimpleInterest()  
{  
    SimpleInterestModel model = new SimpleInterestModel();  
    return View(model);  
}
```

Step 3: Create a strongly-typed view

```
@model CalculateSimpleInterest.Models.SimpleInterestModel  

@{  
    ViewBag.Title = "SimpleInterest";  
}  

<h2>Calulate Simple Interest</h2>  

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CalculateSimpleInterestResult","CalculateSimpleInterest",  
                            new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divInterestDeatils" }))  
    {  

    <fieldset>  
        <legend>Calulate Simple Interest</legend>  
        <div id="divInterestDeatils"></div>  

        <div class="editor-label">  
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount)  
        </div>  
        <div class="editor-field">  
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount)            
        </div>  

        <div class="editor-label">  
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rate)  
        </div>  
        <div class="editor-field">  
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Rate)            
        </div>  

        <div class="editor-label">  
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Year)  
        </div>  
        <div class="editor-field">  
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Year)             
        </div>  
        <p>  
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate" />  
        </p>  
    </fieldset>  
}  

@section Scripts {  
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")  
}
```

Step 4: Create an action method that handles the POST request and processes the data

In the action method we pass a model as the parameter. That model has UI input field data. Here we do not need to parse and do not need to write extra code.

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult CalculateSimpleInterestResult(SimpleInterestModel model)  
{  
    decimal simpleInteresrt = (model.Amount*model.Year*model.Rate)/100;  
    StringBuilder sbInterest = new StringBuilder();  
    sbInterest.Append("<b>Amount :</b> " + model.Amount+"<br/>");  
    sbInterest.Append("<b>Rate :</b> " + model.Rate + "<br/>");  
    sbInterest.Append("<b>Time(year) :</b> " + model.Year + "<br/>");  
    sbInterest.Append("<b>Interest :</b> " + simpleInteresrt);  
    return Content(sbInterest.ToString());  
}
```